# How to use API Auth using Django MongoEngine REST?

Tags: django, mongodb, rest

I'm building an API REST using Django and MongoDB with django-rest-framework-mongoengine package from https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine

How can I use Django Rest Framework API TokenAuthentication if this package does not use Django's built in ORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by handling TokenAuthentication or any other type of DRF auth using Django's build in ORM with MySQL database (Just to handle API authentication). I use MongoDB as my primary system database. So yes, i'm using two databases, one for auth API and the other for transactions.

Don't know if this is the best way to achieve this but it works.

I hope this helps to anyone who's trying or thinking to work with this architecture :)

Comment: How do you manage Relationships between your collections and the user table ?

Comment: Well, I guess I need to wade my way out. In my current situation, I need to implement this using mongoDB as the only database. Please give me a heads up if things have changed since your this post.